Callback function not found using trace in tkinter
I am having an error trying to trace a variable in tkinter. Any idea?
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar(root)
var.trace("w", lambda unused0, unused1, unused2: callback)
ideal_segment_size_spin = Spinbox(root,from_=0, to=100, increment=0.1,textvariable=var)

def callback(*args):
    pass

The error is : NameError: name 'callback' is not defined.
The function is actually called and executed, but the error pops out anyway.

Move the definition of callback() before var.trace(...).  Also it should be var.trace("w", callback) instead.

It has nothing to do with Tkinter and nothing to do with callback functions. It's the exact same reason why writing print(one) first and one = 1 after that doesn't work. "The function is actually called and executed" - no, it isn't. Not by the code shown here, anyway.

It is because when the trace is triggered, callback() has not been defined.
Move the definition of callback() to before var.trace(...).  Note also that lambda is not necessary for your case:
from tkinter import *

def callback(*args):
    print(args)

root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar(root)
var.trace_add("write", callback)
ideal_segment_size_spin = Spinbox(root,from_=0, to=100, increment=0.1, textvariable=var)
...

Note also that .trace() will be deprecated, use .trace_add() instead.
